# How to impress a teacher so you can get a PH D despite bad qualifications?

Tags: thesis

how do ask for a teacher to let you do a Ph D thesis despite your qualifications are bad ?

a) invent a new formula (even a useless one)

b) to solve an unsolved hypothesis : this is the hardest option

are there any other options ? i would like to do a thesis i have a master degree (FISYMAT) and a degree on physics but my qualifications are 'bad'  1.45 of 4

what can i do ? i have had some ideas and formulae that could be interesting :http://vixra.org/author/jose_javier_garcia_moreta

but they are not groundbreaking :( so what should i do ?

Comment: You might search for vixra on this stack to see how it tends to be viewed in this community.

Comment: A teacher won't just let you do a PhD thesis - you need to go through the application process.  Do you mean to say your GPA is 1.45? If so, your chances are very low unfortunately...

Comment: Since you have a Master's, I would have a chat with your advisor about your current options.  I wouldn't upload more to vixra, which has a bad reputation.

Comment: well can not publish into the elitist arxiv.org :( so i have to upload there

Comment: also which forum would be a respectable site to speak about math ? i am currenty at physicsforums.com

Comment: @JairTaylor: Do you want to say that this is true all over the world?! In my country, your teacher could just accept you without such process.

Comment: @user111955 Ah, I only know the US process.

Comment: @JoseJavierGarcia I'm not sure about physics, but MathOverflow is the most respected Q&A forum for math.  But it's not a place to put out original research unless it's in answer to a question.  Since you have a degree, I'd think you could get endorsement for the arxiv via your institution.

Comment: Surprised that you found physics SE but not the maths SE? https://math.stackexchange.com/  MathsOverflow is better and if you do well there, people might be able to provide options and suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I see you are in Maths Overflow and have 4.2K in the Maths SE group. Are you able to build a strong portfolio of issues that you have tackled and argue your professional mathematics competency? Why are you not performing as well in MathsOverflow? Some professors do respond and give you complex problems to solve to demonstrate your skill.

Comment: I don't think inventing a useless formula will help.

Comment: Btw, it is far better to produce mathematics PDFs via LaTeX than Microsoft word, if only because that's the "current industry standard". In particular, non-TeX documents already raise a small red flag in the minds of many.

Comment: also i am forty years old :D now is this also a handicap ?? :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume in my answer that when you say "qualification" you mean GPA. I am not familiar with the University of Granada - all my experience with academia has been in the US and Europe - so keep that in mind.

As already noted, PhD candidates are not expected to produce a work which will shake a field to its core. I see it more of proof that you can think critically and creatively, and that you have the stamina to deal with a major research project. In that way, it is more about jumping through hoops than creating your *magna opus*...

The application process in most Tier 1 universities has at least two parts. First, most universities have a "graduate school" which will make sure that all candidates meet some set of general requirements. Second, each department will usually have their own additional requirements. This is handled somewhat differently in  different schools, but in my experience the graduate school will generally use a GPA/GRE/LSAT cutoff, while the department will take a closer look at subject grades, letters of recommendation, statement of purpose, etc...

With a low GPA I think you would have to do a few things as faculty support on its own might not be enough:

1) Take a good look at how the universities you are considering set GPA requirements. Do they consider cumulative GPA or graduate school GPA? Do they take all your years in school into account? Do they look at courses relevant to the degree?

2) Do well on standardized tests. What weight is given to standardized tests? Would a high GRE/LSAT/GMAT/etc weight out a low GPA?

3) What role does faculty have in this process? Can you find a professor or two in your preferred schools with whom you could work? I find that strong candidates usually reach out to faculty *before* applying, but faculty do not necessarily have the power to push a candidate through the process. So this can help, but it is not the deciding factor.

Finally, make sure that your motivations for pursuing a PhD are clear. Do you want to pursue an academic career? Research? Consulting? Private sector? It is vital that you find a faculty mentor who understands and is sympathetic to your motivation (not just your research question). It is even more important that *you* know why you are pursuing a PhD. It is quite different from a masters in content, context, and outcome.

Good luck!

Comment: so what should i do ? i could send all the PDF with my ideas to some teacher and hope he/she gives me a help ? how i could convince him/her to proof that i could perorm a thesis if the math are not so higher ? , could i submit my PDF to teachers to see that i can have some new ideas :( and wait for a response ?

Comment: Isn't Granada in Spain? Also, apart maybe from the UK, there seem to be very few universities in Europe that have dedicated graduate schools.

Comment: If you do send ideas to anyone, rather than discussing motivation and, I hope, why your standardized test scores are higher than your GPA, I suggest sending a carefully selected small set of your very best ideas, not a general dump.

Comment: and not out of the blue!

Comment: I agree with Patricia and Fabio: be careful what you send and don't just mail your work to people. I would suggest doing some research on the faculty you want to reach. Have a look a their resume, their publication history, their LinkedIN profile, etc... First ask for an informational interview and ask questions about their program, university, research, living in their city, TA/RA opportunities, and the like. Then follow-up and ask if they would be wiling to look at some of your work and explain your situation. Make sure that you have a good story and be ready for questions.

Answer (score 9):

Science isn't about groundbreaking discovery, those are sci-fi movies.

Real science is about boring consistency. You don't need to solve the Riemann hypothesis, you need to demonstrate you can churn out a few good enough papers a year with minimal supervision. Include some funding proposals in there, bam MVP :)

Unfortunately for you, grades are a reasonable proxy measure for boring consistency.  The reasoning being: good grades imply that you can understand new content and have the discipline to put the hours to get a decent grade doing boring work unrelated to your interests. So you would need to demonstrate with papers, which is significantly harder (and takes a while), and this idea will backfire if the papers aren't good enough...

Comment: I would argue that grades in undergraduate exams are a terrible proxy for  research ability. However, in the absence of other information, they are what academic staff and funding bodies have to go on, and when inundated with applications they make a good filter.

Comment: That's why I said they indicate 'boring consistency'. If you can do well in boring (almost) unrelated courses, you probably have enough discipline to do well in research, even if you are not brilliant. That's what I meant.

Comment: +1 Proving the Riemann Hypothesis isn't necessary to get into grad school. Convincing an admissions committee that if admitted you're likely to be able to successfully complete the program *is* necessary however. And things like grades and letters of recommendation are how you do the convincing.

Answer (score 2):

My experience is limited to certain countries in Europe.

I was in a similar position when I was applying for PhD's. My grades have never been good, so I had to set myself apart in other ways.

My advice would be to talk to your master's supervisor about trying to publish something. That would help prove that you are capable of doing research and developing it into a story.

I would also (as others have suggested) recommend researching PIs in your field of interest and sending them e-mails. You don't need to wow them in that email, just introduce yourself, say what your masters topic was, say why you want to do a PhD in this field, and then ask if they have any openings. Even if they don't, I found that many people were happy to pass me on to someone who did have money for students, simply because they could see that I was interested.

Good luck!